Pytorch .backward() error when trying to compute policy gradient for offline RL
I am consistently getting a backward pass error or an inplace autograd error whenever trying to use a memory buffer to train my policy.
Here is the function that causes the issues:
def reinforce(pi, episodes, max_steps = 100, actor_fpath = 'actor.pth', critic_fpath = 'critic.pth', decay = False):
    '''
    In this function instead of using advantage estimation and training online we implement policy gradients using
    gains and implement the REINFORCE algorithm for on-policy optimization
    '''
    optimizer_actor = optim.AdamW(pi.parameters(), lr=p_lr)
    running_avg_reward = 0
    alpha = 1e-2
    mem = ReplayMemory(maxlen=2*max_steps)

    for e in range(episodes):
        state = sample_non_colliding(sample_state, is_colliding, sample_bounds)
        traj = []
        done = False
        steps = 0

        while not done and steps < max_steps:
            # Sample an action and step the environment
            action, logprob = pi.sample(state)
            next_state, reward, done = step_env(state, action)

            # Update running average of reward
            running_avg_reward = (1-alpha)*running_avg_reward + alpha * reward

            # Apped this transition to our trajectory
            traj.append([state, action, next_state, reward, logprob])
            steps += 1

        # Compute the gain at all steps and add this to our replay buffer
        traj = compute_gain(traj)
        mem.add_trajectory(traj)

        # Train our policy
        data = DataLoader(mem, batch_size=policy_bs, shuffle=True)
        for i, batch in enumerate(data):
            if i > 10: break
            gains = batch['gains']
            logprobs = batch['logprobs']

            weight = (gains - running_avg_reward).unsqueeze(1).detach()
            actor_loss = (-logprobs * weight).sum()
            optimizer_actor.zero_grad()
            actor_loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
            optimizer_actor.step()
        
        if e % 100 == 0:
            success_rate, avg_reward_per_step, avg_reward_per_episode = evaluate_policy(pi, trials=50, maxsteps=50)
            print(f'Episode: {e}, Success rate: {success_rate}, average reward per step: {avg_reward_per_step}, avg reward per episode {avg_reward_per_episode}')
            if decay: pi.decay_variance()

Here is the error I get if I do not set retain_graph = True in actor_loss.backward():
Sinas-MacBook-Pro:actor_critic shazeghi$ python vanilla_pg.py 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/graph.py:825: UserWarning: Error detected in torch::autograd::CopySlices. Traceback of forward call that caused the error:
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/vanilla_pg.py", line 237, in <module>
    reinforce(pi, 5)
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/vanilla_pg.py", line 123, in reinforce
    mem.add_trajectory(traj)
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/policy.py", line 95, in add_trajectory
    self.push(s, a, ns, r, lp, g)
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/policy.py", line 85, in push
    self.logprobs[self.position] = lp
 (Triggered internally at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/python_anomaly_mode.cpp:115.)
  return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/vanilla_pg.py", line 237, in <module>
    reinforce(pi, 5)
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/vanilla_pg.py", line 135, in reinforce
    actor_loss.backward()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 581, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 347, in backward
    _engine_run_backward(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/graph.py", line 825, in _engine_run_backward
    return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.


Now if I set retain_graph = True I get this error:
actor_critic shazeghi$ python vanilla_pg.py 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/graph.py:825: UserWarning: Error detected in AddmmBackward0. Traceback of forward call that caused the error:
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/vanilla_pg.py", line 237, in <module>
    reinforce(pi, 5)
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/vanilla_pg.py", line 111, in reinforce
    action, logprob = pi.sample(state)
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/policy.py", line 38, in sample
    mu = self.forward(state)
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/policy.py", line 23, in forward
    out2 = self.tanh(self.layer2(out1))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1736, in _wrapped_call_impl
    return self._call_impl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1747, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/linear.py", line 125, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
 (Triggered internally at /Users/runner/work/pytorch/pytorch/pytorch/torch/csrc/autograd/python_anomaly_mode.cpp:115.)
  return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/vanilla_pg.py", line 237, in <module>
    reinforce(pi, 5)
  File "/Users/shazeghi/Documents/Comp_Robotics/advanced_robotics/actor_critic/vanilla_pg.py", line 135, in reinforce
    actor_loss.backward(retain_graph = True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 581, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 347, in backward
    _engine_run_backward(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/torch/autograd/graph.py", line 825, in _engine_run_backward
    return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.FloatTensor [12, 2]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 3; expected version 1 instead. Hint: the backtrace further above shows the operation that failed to compute its gradient. The variable in question was changed in there or anywhere later. Good luck!

It's strange because whenever I try to train my policy online the same loss computations and gradients work fine but when using a memory buffer it runs into this issue. In case it is needed here is some additional code that defines my Policy, and ReplayMemory classes:
class Policy(nn.Module):
    '''
    Learns a parametrized actor network that takes in state (x_t, y_t, xdot_t, ydot_t) and returns mu_x, mu_y
    means of 2 gaussian's. We sample these gaussians to obtain action a_t = (u_x, u_y)
    '''
    def __init__(self, hidden_size, input_size = 4, output_size = 2, var = 0.1, var_decay = 0.99) -> None:
        super(Policy, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)    
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.var = var
        self.gamma = var_decay
        self.relu = nn.LeakyReLU()
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
    
    def forward(self, state: torch.tensor):
        out1 = self.relu(self.layer1(state))
        out2 = self.tanh(self.layer2(out1))
        return out2
    
    def decay_variance(self):
        self.var *= self.gamma
    
    
    def sample(self, state: torch.tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        '''
        This method sample's an action given a state.
        Does this by computing a predicted mean mu for each action DoF and samples
        From a gaussian using the mean and it's own set variance

        returns action and logprobs of that action
        '''
        mu = self.forward(state)
        distr = dist.Normal(mu, self.var)

        # action = torch.clip(distr.sample(), -1, 1).clone()
        action = distr.sample()
        # print(f'action: {action}, {action.shape}') DEBUG PRINT

        logprobs = distr.log_prob(action)
        # print(logprobs) DEBUG PRINT

        return action, logprobs


class ReplayMemory(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, maxlen=500, s_shape=4, a_shape=2, dtype=torch.float32):
        self.maxlen = maxlen
        self.current_size = 0
        self.position = 0
        
        # Defer tensor creation until we see the first sample
        self.states = torch.zeros(size=(maxlen, s_shape), dtype=dtype)
        self.actions = torch.zeros(size=(maxlen, a_shape), dtype=dtype)
        self.rewards = torch.zeros(size = (maxlen, ), dtype=dtype)
        self.next_states = torch.zeros(size=(maxlen, s_shape), dtype=dtype)
        self.gains = torch.zeros(size = (maxlen, ), dtype=dtype)
        self.logprobs = torch.zeros(size=(maxlen, a_shape), dtype=dtype)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.current_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return {
            'state': self.states[idx],
            'action': self.actions[idx],
            'reward': self.rewards[idx],
            'next_state': self.next_states[idx],
            'gains': self.gains[idx],
            'logprobs': self.logprobs[idx]
        }

    def push(self, s, a, ns, r, lp, g):
        
        # Store transition in the circular buffer
        self.states[self.position] = s
        self.actions[self.position] = a
        self.rewards[self.position] = r
        self.next_states[self.position] = ns
        self.logprobs[self.position] = lp
        self.gains[self.position] = g
        
        # Update position and size
        self.position = (self.position + 1) % self.maxlen
        self.current_size = min(self.current_size + 1, self.maxlen)

    def add_trajectory(self, trajectory):
        for t in trajectory:
            s, a,ns, r, lp, g = t
            self.push(s, a, ns, r, lp, g)
 

I've tried detaching various tensors such as advantage and weight. I've tried using regular lists instead of Replay memory to store gains and log probabilities. I've tried implementing an offline version of a2c similar to the above reinforce implementation but with a Value network and always notice that the actor_loss.backward has a problem

after some reading I realized that the inplace error is happening because PyTorch doesn't expect us to use the logprobs stored in ReplayMemory in order to compute the loss used to update our policy.
This is because as we update our policy, the underlying graph within the logprobs we are training over is no longer the same as the weights in our policy network. I was able to get around this by computing logprobs on the fly with my policy and then computing the loss w.r.t that instead of using ReplayMemory to store it.
It is still useful to store logprobs in ReplayMemory as that can be used to implement something like the importance sampling and clipping used in PPO and it can show how our policy distribution changes over time. Below is the new code that works:
        # Train our policy
        data = DataLoader(mem, batch_size=bs, shuffle=True)
        for i, batch in enumerate(data):
            if i > 10: break
            gains = batch['gains']
            states = batch['state']
            actions = batch['action']
            logprobs = pi.get_logprob(states, actions)

            weight = (gains - running_avg_reward).unsqueeze(1).detach()
            actor_loss = (-logprobs * weight).sum()
            optimizer_actor.zero_grad()
            actor_loss.backward()
            optimizer_actor.step()

